# If diam(A) < r, show that A $\subset B_r(a)$ for some $a \in A$.

Tags: limits, metric-spaces

Set in a generic metric space (M, d), given set A with diam(A) < r.

Show that A $\subset B_r(a)$ for some $a \in A$, where $B_r(a) = \{y\in M:d(x,y)\leq r\}$.

I think that I know how to show this. If diam(A) < r this means that the supremum of d(a, b) for $a,b\in A$ is smaller than r. So if you pick a point y in A and take $B_r(y)$, you know that $B_r(y)$ includes A, since the largest value you can get for d(y,z) with point $z \in A$ is smaller than r.

**Q:** The way this exercise is posed though, it seems as if it only holds for some $a \in A$. Doesn't it hold that A $\subset B_r(a)$ for all $a\in A$?

Comment: What kind of metric space is "generic"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it holds for all $a$, you are right about that.

Note that because "$ \forall \Rightarrow \exists$" the original statement is not wrong,
and just because it sounds like it only holds for some $a\in A$, it can also hold for all $a\in A$.

*Edit*:
For the case that $A$ is empty, you cannot take $a\in A$, but every $a\in M$ works.

Comment: Shouldn't the exercise stipulate that $A$ is nonempty?